# What is the correct exception when trying to create a Django record when only one record is allowed

Tags: django, exception

If it did make it all the way to the database, it's obviously an IntegrityError. However, if this is happening *before* it makes it to the database -- say, in a save method in a Manager class -- what would be the proper exception to raise?

Example:

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def create_from_user(self, user):
        try:
            existing = self.get(user=user)
            raise Exception("There is already an object for this user.") # more specific exception needed
        except self.DoesNotExist:
            # begin creating the record
```

Because of the nature of the record, I do not want a get_or_create type situation (I want using this method when the record already exists to be a hard error that throws an Exception).

Assuming that I put unique constraints on my table, obviously eventually an IntegrityError would be thrown but I'd rather not rely on this and instead make this explicit in the code. But I'm not sure what exception is most accurate (or if I must roll my own).

Answer (score 8):

I'd say this was a `ValidationError`. That's what Django throws in the form and model clean methods when it encounters a duplicate entry on a unique field.

Comment: This seems closer. I'll probably go with this unless someone can convince me otherwise.

Comment: ValidationError is What I would use too here - and in fact what I already use for similar situations.

Answer (score 2):

Why not throw an `IntegrityError` yourself? In a sense, your database related code has detected that an integrity problem is about to occur. There's no need to make up a different error / exception to describe something that already has a name.

Comment: What gives me pause is this in the PEP: "Exception raised when the relational integrity of the database is affected, e.g. a foreign key check fails." Due to the way the database is arranged, it may or may not affect the relational integrity and in fact due to legacy data I probably can't put those constraints on the database.

Comment: In that case you could throw a `DatabaseError`, the parent class of `IntegrityError` with your own error message or create a subclass of `DatabaseError` specifically for this situation (e.g., `SaveIntegrityError`).

Comment: Hmmm... I just looked at a comparable function `User.objects.create_user` and it doesn't attempt to do an error catching and relies on the database. So maybe that's what I should do and just go ahead and normalize the database as best as I can. I guess the idea is that managers should assume everything's hunky dory and rely on the database to catch these errors...